# ASP.Net MVC ModelBinder.BindProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to build a ModelBinder that can be used on multiple different models. It's only job is to convert any decimal to currency. Here is my code:

```
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
        {
            var possibleDecimal = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
            if (possibleDecimal != null)
            {
                decimal d = 0;
                if (decimal.TryParse(possibleDecimal.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out d))
                {
                    propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, d);
                }
                else
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState[propertyDescriptor.Name].Errors.Add("Decimal is not currency.");
                }
            }
        }
        else base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

In this code block, possibleDecimal is always null. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Since `IValueProvider.GetValue` returns null, probably the key provided with `propertyDescriptor.Name` is empty or missing. From what instance `propertyDescriptor` getting its value?

Comment: Right after I posted this, I think I found my problem, but wanted to wait and see if I got a better answer. My Acton in my controller is bound to an array, so form values come in like: [0].PropertyName or [1].propertyName. is this causing my null value?